# Mount directory at startup --bind option

Tags: mount, bind

I am mounting already my directory Music from /bakup in my home folder Music using this method:

```
sudo mount --bind -o default /bakup/Music $HOME/Music/
```

how can I do, to autoexec this at the startup system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your favorite text editor and root privileges, add the following line to `/etc/fstab`.

```
/bakup/Music /home/george/Private        none    bind
```

(replace `george` with your username)

See this Server Fault [post](https://serverfault.com/a/613183/269326) for the full answer.

Comment: No problem. Anytime! :)